# Magento product configuration and color swatches

Tags: magento, configuration, admin, product, color-picker

I'm setting up a swimwear catalog and I'm hoping someone can give me some guidance for setting up the products properly.

This is essentially what I want to do:
http://www.nafnaf.com/fr/robe.html/

I found this extension and it does pretty much the same thing:
http://cjmcreativedesigns.com/pre-select-colors-plus-swatches.html

I like this plugin because it does color swatches on the list and details page and on the layered navigation in Magento. The process for this plugin is to setup a configurable product (Swimsuit A) and a simple product for each corresponding color (Swimsuit A - Red, Swimsuit A - B etc). When viewing the configurable product (Swimsuit A) and you click on a swatch it will load all the images from the simple product and populate the preview and thumbnails.

Does anyone know of a way I can automate this somehow or know of a better way I can make the color swatches work without setting up tons of simple products? The only thing I've come up with is to use this plugin:

Automatic Configurables
http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/automatic-configurables.html

Which will automate creating simple products for configurables.

If anyone has any feedback I'd be really grateful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The idea of Configurable product is to have an attribute combination to be matched to a specific Simple product. In such a way:

- You have real products, that represent a combination of options a customer can configure. Thus system can track separate inventories for all these products. And show that products in a search list as separate products.
- The products are linked together, composing families of products. Thus it is possible for a system to let customer change some options of one product in a family, in order to buy similar product from the same family.

So, if you want to have different products at the list, ability to configure product at detail page, then you need to have physically different products in a catalog. There is no way to avoid it.

The possible ways to make the process easier are:

1. Use Automatic Configurables. Seems that it solves your problem. So
   why don't just use it? :)
2. Use Import/Export Magento's feature to import pre-composed
   configurables. Then you can try to automate task not on Magento
   creation of products, but rather on generation of these lists.
3. Hire a Magento developer and make him create a generator for your
   needs. This is not hard.
4. Switch from Configurable to Simple products with Custom Options. In
   such a way you don't need to create Simple product for every option
   configuration. But you lose inventory tracking, separate products at search list. And you lose granular combinations management. I.e. when having product with S/M sizes and Red/Blue
   colors, Configurable may let you setup to have "Blue S", "Red S",
   "Red M" combinations only (it means, you don't have "Blue M" product). While Simple with Custom Options will     always make system to let user chose from full set of option
   combinations: "Blue S", "Blue M", "Red S", "Red M". You don't have a way to tell system, that your inventory doesn't have a product with particular options combination.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Hey also, is there any way to do inventory tracking for custom options like sizes in Magento?

 http://www.mageworx.com/advanced-product-options-magento-extension.html .. is the only way I found so far ? Do you think it's better to create separate products for sizes?

Comment: It is always better to have a model (products in your online store) being as mush close to real world object (products in your stock) as possible. Thus it is better to use configurable product with separate products for different sizes - in such a way inventory tracking is the most straightforward.